# How to use node-xmpp and how i can run it to see in action?

Tags: node.js, xmpp

I want to learn to use node-xmpp but i don't understand how to run this to see how is working.I've tried to install node-xmpp-server and node -xmpp-client.I want to see a working example.Thanks very much !